# SQL on android studio Query

Tags: android, sql

I'm new in android studio and java language, I mean, i know C,C++ and C#   and Java isn't hard. But i need work with a code that was made by another person.

i dont know what he try in as specific part of code.

```
       private java.sql.Connection getConnection() 
    {
        try {
                 Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                 if(s.ConfServer_IP.compareTo("Server") == 0)
                 {
                     connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ s.ConfServer +":"+ s.ConfPuerto +";databaseName="+s.ConfDataBaseName, s.ConfUser, s.ConfPassDB); 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ s.ConfIP +":"+ s.ConfPuerto +";databaseName="+s.ConfDataBaseName, s.ConfUser, s.ConfPassDB);
                 }
                     if (connection != null)
                             System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
             } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     System.out.println("Error Trace in getConnection() : "
                                     + e.getMessage());
                     publishProgress(6);//Error al conectarse a la base de datos
             }
             return connection;
     }
```

I think i have iusses in Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

If someone can help me I will be grateful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you were talking about creates a new Object of the class "**net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver**" by loading the class first(if not already loaded) by calling its default constructor.